Mongo collection to Duckdb in python
I want to create a table in the duckdb database from mongo collection in python, for further analytics. Now I do the following:

dump mongo collection as jsonl to disk (single file)
open duckdb connection and load jsonl file into a table

with open(f"mongo_json.jsonl", "w") as file:
       json.dump(list(mongo_cursor), file, default=str)

duckdb.sql(f"CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE mongo_table AS SELECT *,  FROM read_json_auto('mongo_json.jsonl', IGNORE_ERRORS=true)")


But the thing is the json is really big, which increase the memory consumption. So Are there any ideas or better approach to achieve this ?

https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/issues/11684 was a recent question about read_json_auto memory usage and the recommendation was to use ndjson/jsonl - which is what you doing here. Are you saying your approach works and the problem is just large memory usage?

Yes, exactly the problem is in duckdb. Any idea how to fix this issue?

You can try changing the default memory limits: https://duckdb.org/docs/configuration/overview.html#examples Other than that - you may need to talk to the duckdb people if you don't get any further feedback here.

If your data could fit into memory, check out pymongoarrow (link). You can use it to grab arrow tables from mongo which can easily be ingested into duckdb. You might even be able to do this in chunks to prevent going oom.

Thank you for the info, but the problem is I do not know the schema, and the data inside mongoDB is inconsistent
